# Нарезка и вёрстка нестандартного шаблона

Tags: html, css

Всем привет. Попался мне шаблон у которого секции не прямоугольные. Я пробовал его нарезать, но у мня вышло не очнь хорошо всё это(код ниже будет) и пытался всё делать спомощью клипартов. В общем я зашел в тупик. Подскажите как правильно вестать такие секции.
Код с исспользованием after

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper{
  max-width: 970px;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1086px;
  background-image: url(http://s020.radikal.ru/i718/1610/53/2e62f2d87942.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.spiker {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1371px;
  background-image: url(http://s017.radikal.ru/i416/1610/f3/0f627944ef70t.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;

}

.spiker::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 163px;
  top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(http://s45.radikal.ru/i110/1610/c3/9837344ef991t.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  content: '';
    
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<header>
</header>

<section class="spiker">
</section>


</div>
```

Код с клипартами

```css
body {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
header{
  width: 280px;
 height: 280px;
 background: red;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 75%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 75%);
}
.section1{
  width: 280px;
 height: 280px;
 background: #1e90ff;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 30%, 100% 100%, 0 75%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 30%, 100% 100%, 0 75%);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header></header>
  <section class="section1"></section>
</body>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Учитывая, насколько слабо поддерживается `clip-path`, не лучше ли было бы использовать `transform:rotate` с заранее повёрнутым изображением (или использовать `transform:skew`, само изображение внутри возвращать назад с `transform:skew` в обратную сторону и обрезать всё это с `overflow:hidden`)?

Comment: А с этой секцией что мне делать? http://s009.radikal.ru/i308/1610/76/362388ea4728.jpg

Comment: Если фон чёрный, можно вообще обойтись одним SVG, например. Ну или поставить на фон три чёрных блока, верхний и нижний skew’нуты.

Comment: Ээээ я не понимаю

Comment: там не просто чёрный фон там картинка и боле того оно так в фотошопе уже нарезано

Comment: Вообще, кстати, всё можно было бы сделать на [SVG](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/path-pattern-fill.svg). Логичнее всего, по-моему.

Comment: Я не разу не делал секции с помощью SVG. Да и с помощью SVG вообще ничего не делал. только читал про него. Где есть примеры подобного?

Comment: Вот неплохой пример с `transform:skew`: http://codepen.io/pipozoft/pen/vBwjl. С SVG я погорячился, прошу прощения, с ним не обойтись без JS, так что это уже, можно сказать, и не вёрстка.

Comment: Спасибо пригодиться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.el1, .el2, .el3 {
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.el1 {
  background: url(https://unsplash.it/600?image=1080) no-repeat;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 77%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 77%);
}

.el2 {
  background: url(https://unsplash.it/600?image=1068) no-repeat;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 23%, 100% 100%, 0 77%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 23%, 100% 100%, 0 77%);
  margin-top: -120px;
}

.el3 {
  background: url(https://unsplash.it/600?image=1063) no-repeat;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 22%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 22%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  margin-top: -120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="el1"></div>
<div class="el2"></div>
<div class="el3"></div>
```

Comment: Не работает пример

Comment: @mJeevas в каком браузере не работает?

Comment: в firefox не работает

Answer (score 0):

1. ставишь картинки на фон, сверху них делаешь блоки прямоугольники и к ним применяешь transform:skew.
2. можно сразу к фото применять transform:skew.

p.s. судя по тому, что фото не повернуты, используйте 1 вариант.

вот пример

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="block3"></div>
</div>



.wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.block1 {
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150");
  background-size: 800px;
  background-position: 50%;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
  border: 2px solid #f00;
}
.block2 {
  border: 2px solid #0f0;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150");
  background-size: 800px;
  background-position: 50%;
  transform: skew(0deg, 10deg);
}
.block3 {
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150");
  background-size: 800px;
  background-position: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  border: 2px solid #00f;
}
```

http://codepen.io/Doker99725/pen/XjwGzd